# Update in qt doesn't work for sql database

Tags: postgresql, qt

This is my code, database doesn't update in ыйд and in qt.

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("UPDATE employee SET initials = :initials WHERE employee_id =:employee_id;");
query.bindValue("initials", "Karter");
query.bindValue(":employee_id", 5);
query.exec();
```

Comment: Shouldn't this `"initials", "Karter"` be `":initials", "Karter"`?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Adrian, i missed a colon

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("UPDATE employee SET initials = :initials WHERE employee_id =:employee_id;");
query.bindValue(":initials", "Karter");//missed : here
query.bindValue(":employee_id", 5);
query.exec();
```